# Guardar checked en locaStorage

Tags: reactjs

Tengo una pagina que es un todoApp, ya creo las tareas y las guardo en una ul, dentro del li coloco un input checkbox para marcarlas como completas, la tarea a realizar y un boton para eliminar, ya guardo las tareas en el localStarage y la puedo eliminar y marcar como completas usando un id, el problema es que cuando marco una tarea como completa, el checkbox se selecciona y al texto de la tarea se le agrega un text-decoration line-through, pero al recargar la pagina el texto de la tarea sigue como completa, pero el checkbox se desmarca, como puedo hacer para que si el checkbox este activo al recargar la pagina siga manteniendo ese valor de checked?

**Codigo del componente y la funcion del onChange**

```
const tareaCompleta = (id, e) => {

        if(e.target.checked){
            const action = {
                type: 'completa',
                payload: id,
            }
    
            dispatch(action)

        }else{
            const action = {
                type: 'completa',
                payload: id,
            }
    
            dispatch(action)
        }
    }

    return (
        <ul className="list-group">
            <li
                className={`list-group-item d-flex align-items-center py-2 ${tarea.completa ? 'complete' : null} `}
            >
                <input 
                    type="checkbox"
                    onChange={(e) => tareaCompleta(tarea.id, e)}
                />
                <p className="m-0 cursor-pointer"><span className="fw-bold">{index + 1}. </span>{tarea.descripcion}</p>
                <button
                    onClick={() => eliminarTarea(tarea.id)}
                    className="btn btn-danger px-1 py-0"
                >X</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con lo poco que veo del código, creo que el problema es el siguiente:

```js
<input 
  type="checkbox"
  onChange={(e) => tareaCompleta(tarea.id, e)}
/>
```

Tu checkbox sabe cuándo actualizar, pero nunca está recibiendo cuál es el value que debe mostrar. Entonces a pesar de existir el valor no lo está usando (para el checkbox, pero si para tachar)

```js
<input 
  value={tarea.completa}
  type="checkbox"
  onChange={(e) => tareaCompleta(tarea.id, e)}
/>
```

Comment: El resultado es el mismo, marco el checkbox y la tarea se marca como completa, al recargar la pagina el checkbox se reinicia, pero la tarea continua con el valor de completa

Comment: Puedes subir on codesandbox con tu código para probar?

Comment: si. https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-nobel-j2i2x es este, ya puedo eliminar, marcar como completas, solo que al recargar la pagina, el checked si elimina y la "tarea" continua como completa